# Android Butterknife strange behaviour

Tags: android

I'm using Butterknife library for Views injections in my Android App. I successfuly binded the button:

```
@Bind(R.id.btn_enter) Button enterButton;
```

I can see it on my screen and interact with. But OnClick injection doesn't work:

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_enter)
    public void lol() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked!");
        Toast.makeText(this, "LOL!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I checked all possible solutions and no result. App is running under debug configuration, so ProGuard is not the reason.

Comment: Have you called `ButterKnife.bind(this);` on your activity?

Comment: Yeap, otherwise i could't use @Bind...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved; I forgot to delete the old call to `setOnClickListener()`. Sorry for the useless question.